# Kali linux doesn't boot automatically

Tags: boot, kali-linux, bios

Kali Linux, which I installed recently doesn't boot up automatically when I turn on the computer. It ends up with grub prompt each time after restart. `ls -l` in grub shell outputs:

```
Device proc: Filesystem type procfs - Sector size 512B - Total size 0KiB
Device memdisk: Filesystem type squash4 - Last modification time 2023-01-30 10:51:57 Monday - Sector size 512B - Total size 828 KiB
Device lvm/elgin--vg-swap_1: No known filesystem detected - Sector size 512B - Total size 1003520KiB
Device lbm/elgin--vg-root: Filesystem type ext* - Last modification time 2023-09-10 08:54:44 Sundaym UUID 017f3393-b329-4b76-beb3-4322232898362 - Sector size 512B - Total size 498077696KiB
Device hd0: No known filesystem detected - Sector size 512B - Total size 500107608KiB
    Partition hd0,gpt3: No known filesystem detected - Partition start at 1025024KiB - Total size 499082240KiB
    Partition hd0,gpt2: Filesystem type ext* - Last modification time 2023-09-10 09:13:40 Sunday, UUID db71657b-f9fa-4fa1-b30b-126c07fce731 - Partition start at 525312KiB - Total size 499712KiB
    Partition hd0,gpt1: Filesystem type fat, UUID D941-C709 - Partition start at 1024KiB - Total size 524288KiB
```

I use below set of commands for manual booting:

```
set root=(hd0,gpt1)
chainloader /efi/kali/grubx64.efi
boot
```

I cannot fix booting from BIOS menu, because boot order list is empty there (see attachment below). As recommended in many places, `sudo update-grub` doesn't help either. I also tried [boot-repair](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/), but that couldn't fix it either. You can see output from the boot-repair [here](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/54ghMb2fMv/).[image]

As and additional context, I had Ubuntu and Gecko distros dual booted before I installed Kali. I installed Kali from official ISO file from kali.org.

Any other ideas to fix my boot configuration?

**EDIT 1**

`efibootmgr -v` output:

```
BootCurrent: 0000 
Timeout: 0 seconds 
BootOrder: 0000,0003,2001,2002,2003 
Boot0000* ubuntu HD(1,GPT,bea0db7c-0576-4635-868f-b6975f97ca4e,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC 
Boot0003* kali HD(1,GPT,bea0db7c-0576-4635-868f-b6975f97ca4e,0x800,0x100000)/File(\EFI\kali\grubx64.efi) 
Boot2001* EFI USB Device RC 
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC 
Boot2003* EFI Network RC
```

**EDIT 2**

`dmidecode --type bios` output:

```
# dmidecode 3.5
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.

Handle 0x0000, DMI type 0, 26 bytes
BIOS Information
        Vendor: Insyde Corp.
        Version: V1.04
        Release Date: 06/08/2020
        Address: 0xE0000
        Runtime Size: 128 kB
        ROM Size: 16 MB
        Characteristics:
                PCI is supported
                BIOS is upgradeable
                BIOS shadowing is allowed
                Boot from CD is supported
                Selectable boot is supported
                EDD is supported
                Japanese floppy for NEC 9800 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
                Japanese floppy for Toshiba 1.2 MB is supported (int 13h)
                5.25"/360 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                5.25"/1.2 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/720 kB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                3.5"/2.88 MB floppy services are supported (int 13h)
                8042 keyboard services are supported (int 9h)
                CGA/mono video services are supported (int 10h)
                ACPI is supported
                USB legacy is supported
                BIOS boot specification is supported
                Targeted content distribution is supported
                UEFI is supported
        BIOS Revision: 1.4
        Firmware Revision: 1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The empty boot priority list in the BIOS menu suggests a problem with UEFI NVRAM boot variables. In Linux, you can use `efibootmgr -v` as root to view the boot variables, and other `efibootmgr` options to modify them.

However, some older UEFI implementations had severe bugs in the management of UEFI NVRAM variables: if your system has such a bug (for example, if the changes made with `efibootmgr` will not "stick"), then only a BIOS update could offer a true fix.

---

Your `efibootmgr` output indicates the system is trying to boot Ubuntu's Secure Boot shim as the primary boot target, and that will start Ubuntu's GRUB.

If Ubuntu is no longer installed on your system, delete its boot variable with:

```
efibootmgr -b 0000 -B
```

Otherwise, switch the boot order to make Kali the primary boot target with:

```
efibootmgr -o 0003,0000,2001,2002,2003
```

It looks like the BIOS menu interface to UEFI boot settings is unusably buggy in your current firmware: I recommend learning to use `efibootmgr` to view and modify the boot settings instead.

Comment: I added my BIOS details to the question as well.